# Вылетает после cin>>a>>b>>c; как быть?

Tags: c

Даны три целых числа и нужно найти их среднее арифметическое.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
     cout<<"Vvedite chisla\n";
     int a,b,c,d;
     cin>>a>>b>>c;
     d=(a+b+c)/3;
     cout<<d;
     getch();
}
```

Comment: @DrummerIF, на линуксе (при условии замены getch и conio.h на getchar) всё компилируется и работает. Правда, надо отметить, что пока у вас расчеты производятся в int, в d будет содержаться округленное до ближайшего целого значение, для получения точных результатов надо использовать float/double.

Comment: @DrummerIF, что именно означает -- **вылетает?**

Мы же не видим результатов ни компиляции, ни запуска.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в a, b или c попадают нечисловые символы. Единственное место, где может полететь, на первый взгляд.

Comment: avp, при введении чисел a, b, c, консольное окно закрывается.

Comment: Логично, что оно будет закрываться. Запускайте свое приложение в отдельно запущенной консоли. А `getch()` просто выбросите.

Объяснение посложнее - нельзя мешать сишные способы чтения и плюсовые.

Объяснение ещё сложнее - `cin` не вычитывает перевод строки. `getch` пытается прочитать символ, натыкается на него. Вычитывает. и уходит на завершение программы.

Comment: KoVadim, getch выбросил, такая же проблема осталась.

Comment: @DrummerIF, зачем вы так упорно ставите вопросу метку C#? По всей вероятности, он к этому языку не имеет отношения.

Comment: @DrummerIF, запустите окошко cmd и в нем запускайте свою программу 

(а еще лучше просто переходите с винды в Linux).

Comment: - запустите консоль (например, с помощью пуск - выполнить - cmd)
- перейдите в нужный каталог (cd C:\Users\....)
- запустите программу, просто введя ее имя и нажав enter.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо!
@avp, я с родной винды не собираюсь на Linux переходить.

Comment: @DrummerIF, возможно, это правильное решение (остаться в винде). 

Трудности закаляют.